# Can I resurrect a corpse that was previously animated as undead?

Tags: dnd-5e, undead, character-death, resurrection

One of my teammates has died in battle. As a noble necromancer, I do not want to carry his corpse to the temple on my shoulders, instead I plan to animate his corpse, so he can walk on its own.

Then, in temple, I can destroy the created zombie and pay for his resurrection. Would he get resurrected properly?

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to bring undead back to life directly, without destroying them first?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55100/is-it-possible-to-bring-undead-back-to-life-directly-without-destroying-them-fi)

Comment: Is your question about the *resurrection* spell specifically? Or any spell that revives a dead creature?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Yes, you can resurrect him.

The resurrection spell says (emphasis mine):

> You touch a dead creature that has been dead for no more than a century, that didn't die of old age, **and that isn't undead**. If the soul is free and willing the target returns to life with all its Hit Points.

Under normal circumstance I would argue that a destroyed/killed undead would no longer count as undead but [Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/709791324656902144) has posted a call on the similar revivify spell:

> If you cast revivify on a zombie, the creature returns as a zombie. **The spell doesn't change creature type.**
>   - Jeremy Crawford

This call would let me extrapolate that it would not be possible. Except that this specific case is actually covered by the MM:

> Once turned into a zombie, a creature can't be restored to life except by
>   powerful magic, such as a resurrection spell.
>   -  MM pg. 315

This would mean the specific case of a resurrection spell (or if you want to be absolutely sure a true resurrection spell) it is able to turn a destroyed zombie back into the person it was before originally killed.

Though you might want to destroy the zombie outside of the temple and carry him the last part as I am guessing that most temples are not happy with zombies walking in.

### Beyond RAW

This case relies on a lot of specific rules and exceptions if tis would come up at my home game I would allow resurrection of mindless destroyed undead like skeletons and zombies. I would not allow revivify even if the spell was cast before a minute has past since the original death.

Comment: What do you make of the JC quote in daze413's answer?

Comment: Also, true resurrection specifically mentions that it works on undead, if you're willing to pay the extra 24,000 gold, you don't even need to kill the zombie.  As a side bonus, true resurrection also removes all curses, diseases and poisons, even if they're magical in nature (it also doesn't impose resurrection sickness that regular resurrection does).

Comment: So if your party member dies, and you need to travel a long distance to the temple, you can animate them so they can walk...

Comment: I think the compelling reason why revivify won't work is that it requires being cast within one minute of death, and `create undead` has a casting time of 1 minute. So... bad luck.

Comment: Pretty sure JC's comment was in answer to a question that alludes that the zombie is still "alive" if you destroy the zombie first it is then an object which doesn't have a creature type. But that is a debated topic.

Comment: I believe the writing is meant to mean that a body that is currently/actively effected by something (that has/ is giving it undeath/unlife,) cannot be restored without removing the effect or source of the undead property (as greater spells & effects such as True Resurrection.) So, raising your soul-evicted friend to be a meat mech piloted by undead energy, and then later violently dismissing the spell so you can have a professional restore then sounds like a viable, albeit roundabout way to revive them

Answer (score 30):

### No, you can't Resurrect your friend

Strictly by RAW, Animate Dead creates an undead creature, the thing is no longer "your friend's corpse", it is now a *zombie* with the zombie game statistics:

> **Animate Dead**
>
> Your spell imbues the target with a foul mimicry of life, raising it as an **undead creature**.

With the above, your teammate has become a zombie, and when destroyed, becomes a dead zombie and not a dead PC.

One of the prerequisites for Resurrection is that the corpse cannot be undead:

> **Resurrection**
>
> You touch a dead creature that has been dead for no more than a century, that didn't die of old age, and **that isn't undead**.

This is further supported by [Jeremy Crawford's tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/709791324656902144):

> If you cast revivify on a zombie, the creature returns as a zombie. **The spell doesn't change creature type.**
>   - Jeremy Crawford

---

You also cannot use Raise Dead on him as Raise Dead also states:

> **Raise Dead**
>
> The spell can't return an **undead creature** to life.

However, *True Resurrection* does not appear to have the same limitations as the previously mentioned spells, so you probably can get someone to cast True Resurrection, if you're able to pay.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94954/discussion-on-answer-by-daze413-can-i-resurrect-a-corpse-that-has-been-animated).

Comment: To clarify; True Resurrection states that it does not require a body. So regardless of what happens to the old body, as long as they have a free soul, True Resurrection will revive them with a new body.

Comment: Does that mean that the meat is forever undead, even when the mechanism that has imputed with the foul energy has been ended? If that's the case any creature could be undead and you wouldn't know until you tried to resurrect or raise undead. Since both require a corpse, this would make it so that even a destroyed undead creature can never become a corpse/object again (merely an undead creature with zero hit points.) The implications are far reaching and certainly at home in a grim dark setting. I'd like to explore this idea further...

Answer (score 18):

### Yes, the character can be resurrected.

Source, MM pg. 315 under Zombies, sub-section Dark Servants:

> Once turned into a zombie, a creature can't be restored to life except by
>   powerful magic, such as a resurrection spell.

This is not specific to the spell *Resurrection* but rather resurrection magic in general. So killing the zombie and bringing the character back to life should be manageable within the rules of most spells so long as they qualify within the bounds of their own restrictions.

However, be careful on timing since the limits on resurrection magic start when the character dies. *Animate Dead* is not the same as *Gentle Repose* and does not extend the duration for which you are able to resurrect a dead character/npc. So for instance, *Revivify* only works if used within a minute of death. *Raise Dead* within the last 10 days.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94955/discussion-on-answer-by-lino-frank-ciaralli-can-i-resurrect-a-corpse-that-has-be).

Answer (score 5):

## The Curse of Strahd adventure suggests this will work

I'm a bit late to answer this question, but I have recently spotted this in Curse of Strahd (pg. 47):

> The shape is Doru, a **vampire spawn** [...] If the characters restrain Doru and either promise him blood or threaten to destroy him, or ***if they kill him and then raise him from the dead***, he recounts the events that led to his downfall [...]

So, if a vampire spawn, which is an undead creature, can be killed and then raised from the dead, this implies that resurrection spells (and fairly weak ones at that, since this is from near the beginning of the adventure, so no way is this referring to spells like *resurrection* or *true resurrection*) can restore a creature to life even if they have been undead since then.

Answer (score 1):

### A less complicated, less risky way to solve the problem: TFD

> As a noble necromancer, I do not want to carry his corpse to the temple on my shoulders

*Animate dead* is a third level spell.  By expending zero spell slots, the noble necromancer can cast Tenser's Floating Disk *as a ritual*, and carry the slain ally to the temple on the disk.  Essential details from the spell description

- 1st level, conjuration (ritual), Casting Time: 1 action {*+10 minutes for ritual*}, Duration: 1 hour
- A circular, horizontal plane of force, 3 feet in diameter and 1 inch
  thick can hold up to 500 pounds.
- If you move more than 20 feet away from it, the disk follows you so
  that it remains within 20 feet of you.

The necromancer may need to stop each hour to cast the ritual again, and then keep walking, but a noble necromancer won't overly strain himself.  Walk at a leisurely pace: that's the noble way.

The necromancer keeps that third level slot in hand, in case anyone tries to interrupt the journey.

> **Rituals**
> Certain spells have a special tag: ritual. Such a spell can be cast following the normal rules for spellcasting, or the spell can be cast as a ritual. The ritual version of a spell takes 10 minutes longer to cast than normal. It also doesn’t expend a spell slot, which means the ritual version of  a spell can’t be cast at a higher level.  (Basic Rules, p. 82)

Comment: Given the title, I don't think getting the body to the temple was the OP's problem, but rather a framing vehicle for asking their actual question.

Comment: @Kirt And I provide the alternate solution for the in game problem, get the body where they want to in order to achieve their aim, and in my case they a third level spell slot. Why, it's almost like I am doing a minor challenge to the frame of the XY in the question. 